# Modifying value of NSArrayController object causes errors

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller, key-value-coding

I have an NSArrayController, and I'm trying to modify a value of the selected object. I am using

```
[[[ideasListController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] setValue:@"test" forKey:@"title"];
```

to try and change the title, but this results in an error:

```
[<__NSDictionaryI 0x10065e6c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key title.
```

I'm fairly new to Cocoa and Objective-C, so I'm afraid I might be missing something rather obvious here.

Comment: Your dictionary is immutable, so you can't change it (that's what <__NSDictionaryI 0x10065e6c0> means).

Comment: @rdelmar that's what it was, would you mind putting that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks so much for catching that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary is immutable (thats what the "I" in <__NSDictionaryI 0x10065e6c0> means), so that's why you get error messages when you try to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[ideasListController insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test" forKey:@"title"] atArrangedObjectIndex:0];
```

**Update:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"] forKey:@"title"];

[ideasListController insertObject:dict atArrangedObjectIndex:0];

[dict release];

NSLog(@"%@", [[ideasListController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Now I get a different error - `-[__NSDictionaryI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100584860`. What could this mean?

Comment: Same error as first comment. I'm not sure what you mean by check key - the key already has a string in it, and is a valid key.

Comment: @penguinrob take a look at updated answer. And try first line: `[ideasListController insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test" forKey:@"title"] atArrangedObjectIndex:0];`.

Comment: The update and the line in your last comment both execute without any errors.